# Given $6t^2 -5t-3$, find a quadratic whose roots are $m-n^2,n-m^2$ without computing $m,n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I am trying to answer the following exercise:

> [image]

I have managed to almost answer it, I noticed that I need to use the answer from another exercise:

> [image]

I just made some calculations a little bit wrong. I went for the solutions of the book and found:

> [image]

Which is akin to what I used in my answer. And there is a problem with both this answer and my "answer" with mistaken calculations: Using the previous exercise, we know that $\frac{-31}{36}=\frac{-b}{a}$ and $\frac{-449}{216}=\frac{c}{a}$, but why do we have two different $a$'s? I thought that there could be two polynomials with different coefficients and same zeroes, but at least here, it is not the case:

> [image]

So how do I pick the right $a$?

Comment: Fractions can be reduced if the numerator and denominator have a common factor $>1$ edit: $216$ is the *least common multiple* of $36$ and $216$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I know, but $449/216$ isn't reducible.

Comment: See edit $\, \, $

Comment: The point is that $-31/36$ is the same thing as $(-31 \cdot 6)/216$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I don't get it. See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=449%2F216).

Comment: Shouldn't we be able to reduce $449/216$, then?

Comment: No,  why? $\, \, $

Comment: I guess you pretty much solved it. I'll take some time to think about it, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'm not explaining well. I guess I mean to say this: just like you can reduce fractions by dividing both numerator and denominator by the same factor, you can also do the opposite, by multiplying both numerator and denominator by the same factor (as I did with -31/36 above). Neither reducing a fraction nor doing this "opposite" actually change the value of the fraction.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I was just using the wrong assumptions. I thought that the "larger" fraction had to be reductible, but it can also happen to be that the "smaller" fraction can be multiplied.

Comment: How do you know Viete's formulas on roots but you don't know how fractions work? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @terrace I just mindlessly assumed that something would work that way without seeing the bigger picture. Thanks for the boost in the self-esteem. xD

Comment: @terrace One day I went to solve $a+x=b$ for $x$. I "found" $x=b/a$ and spent a lot of time trying to figure out what was wrong with all the calculations. I know the solution is $x=b-a$ but somehow, stupidness blocked me that day. I guess it has done the same now! XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m+n=5/6\\mn=-1/2$$
If the roots are $m-n^2$ and $n-m^2$ then the sum of roots is
$$m-n^2+n-m^2=(m+n)-(m+n)^2+2mn=?$$
And product of roots. 
$$(m-n^2)(n-m^2)=mn-n^3-m^3+m^2n^2=mn + m^2n^2-(m+n)(m^2+n^2-mn)\\=mn+m^2n^2-(m+n)((m+n^2)-3mn)$$

Put the values of $m+n$ and $mn$ to get sum and product of roots. This is the answer and **there is no right $a$.** You need to have the correct ratio between $a,b,c$. Their absolute values don't really matter.

Comment: Wait, there is a correct $a$. At least this is what the discussion in the comments seems to tell me. Am I missing something?

Comment: If $ax^2+bx+c$ have $m,n$ as the solution, then $2ax^2+2bx+2c$ will have the same solution. So therefore there no correct a. You can maybe that one with the most reduced form is the most acceptable a.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you meant.